# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when I try to use scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute the statistc S_1/2 for two-point angular correlation function. My code is:

```
# Importing libraries
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import radians

# Converting the degrees into radians
theta_rad=np.radians(theta)

# I define a integrand function
def integrand(theta, C_theta):
    cos_theta = np.cos(theta)
    return -C_theta**2 * np.sin(theta)
def compute_statistic(theta_rad, C_theta):
    integrand_values = lambda theta: integrand(theta, C_theta)
    integral, error = quad(integrand_values, 0, np.pi)  # Adjusted integration limits
    return integral, error

s_half = compute_statistic(theta_rad, C_theta)
print("The value of S_1/2 is:", s_half)
```

And this gives me a following error:

only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

In my opinion integrand_values is a np.ndarray and the quad function  has to have a function.

Have a nice day!

I've been trying to change integrand_values to a function that it gives me a float.

Comment: Show the full error message.  What is `C_theta`?  What does `integrand(0,C_theta)` produce?  It should be a single number for use in `quad`.  `integrand_values` is a `lambda`, which qualifies as a function.

Comment: `quad` needs a function that returns a scalar, and two end points, which are also scalars.  You can provide additional arguments via the `args` parameter, or as you appently do as global.

Comment: Also note that `compute_statistic` takes the argument `theta_rad`, which is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

With your functions, if I give `compute_statistic` two numbers, I get back a result

```
In [4]: compute_statistic(0,0)
Out[4]: (0.0, 0.0)
```

If I make the 2nd one an array, I get your error:

```
In [5]: compute_statistic(0,np.arange(3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 compute_statistic(0,np.arange(3))

Cell In[3], line 7, in compute_statistic(theta_rad, C_theta)
      5 def compute_statistic(theta_rad, C_theta):
      6     integrand_values = lambda theta: integrand(theta, C_theta)
----> 7     integral, error = quad(integrand_values, 0, np.pi)  # Adjusted integration limits
      8     return integral, error

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py:463, in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst, complex_func)
    460     return retval
    462 if weight is None:
--> 463     retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    464                    points)
    465 else:
    466     if points is not None:

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py:575, in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    573 if points is None:
    574     if infbounds == 0:
--> 575         return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    576     else:
    577         return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

OK, the error isn't quite as clear as I hoped, probably because `_qagie`, is a compiled function.  So let's make a guess and see where the `func` returns with this input.

```
In [6]: integrand(0,np.arange(3))
Out[6]: array([ 0., -0., -0.])
```

With array `C_theta`, the function returns an array.  `quad` does not like that!

With scalar values, we get a scalar result, and `quad` runs fine:

```
In [8]: integrand(10, 3)
Out[8]: 4.896189998004328

In [9]: compute_statistic(10,3)
Out[9]: (-18.0, 1.9984014443252818e-13)
```

That first argument, `rad_theta` isn't use. And in `integrand` you calculate a `cos`, but don't use it.  But you do use the `C_theta`.